# What movie is Don watching?

Tags: mad-men

In Season 6, Episode 1 of Mad Men, Don is observed watching something on the television.[image]

Is there a symbolic importance to what is on the television? Given that we're shown what it is, I doubt it is just casually thrown on the TV for no reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the [Donna Reed Show](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Donna_Reed_Show), which ran from 1958 to 1966 and depicted the perfect American family, which is what Don had tried to create with Betty, but failed. If this episode is an indication of things to come, he seems to be heading into a downward spiral.

[image]

Comment: Much better. Bravo.

Comment: Killin it as usual, @MaryJoFinch